# syntax error in VC xtree internal header with Qt/boost project

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm using Boost with a Qt project.
I added these lines to my .pro file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_62_0/
LIBS += "-LC:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-12.0/"
```

I'm linking against boost, as I use a the libICP library, that includes boost/multi_array and boost/array.

When I compile, I get a lot of errors :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree:20: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree:21: error: C2518: keyword 'typename' illegal in base class list; ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree:22: error: C2518: keyword 'typename' illegal in base class list; ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree:132: error: C2065: '_Iterator_base0' : undeclared identifier
```

I suspect xtree is used by the implementation of multi_array or array, but I don't really know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the solution (I was working on this issue since yesterday...)

In case someone else has a similar issue, it was just a case of unbalanced } at the end of the file ICP_Registration.h, that includes libICP.